# Help me out with this problem. getting information for array from one class to another controller class

Tags: iphone

i parsed data from xml....

All the data i stored in an NSMutableArray *eventListArray;
its in class DistanceInfo.

in my controller Class CityEventViewController. displayed data in tableview.

ITs working fine..

I do have another ViewController Called PopularEventViewController....

when i selected my didSelectRowAtIndexPath.....

Its load my popularEventViewController....

Now i need to display the eventListArray data in popularEventViewController in tableview

when i call [aDistanceInfo.eventListArray count].... in view did load

I need to get that data into popularEventViewController... Please help out.

I hope you can understand my problem..

If you want i will post my code.

@Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but I would use the appDelegate for this.  Declare an NSMutableArray in your appdelegate.  Then assign it the value of your first array in CityEvent like so

appDelegate.nameofarraydeclaredinappdelegate = eventListArray;
to retrieve the data in your other viewcontroller do this call

nameofnewarrayinpopularEventViewController = appDelegate.nameofarraydeclaredinappdelegate;